# Showing that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arctan \left( \frac{2}{n^2} \right) =\frac{3\pi}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I would like to show that:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arctan \left( \frac{2}{n^2} \right) =\frac{3\pi}{4}$$

We have:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \arctan \left( \frac{2}{n^2} \right) =\sum_{n=1}^N \arctan (n+1)-\arctan(n-1) =-\frac{\pi}{4}+\arctan N+\arctan(N+1)\rightarrow \frac{3\pi}{4}$$

Do you agree with my proof?

Comment: You have to write $\sum_{n=1}^N \left (\arctan (n+1)-\arctan(n-1)\right )$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything is fine with this proof.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I wanted to hear!