# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}\tan{\left(\tan^{-1}{\frac{2}{1^2}}+\tan^{-1}{\frac{2}{2^2}}+...+\tan^{-1}{\frac{2}{n^2}}\right)}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I need to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\tan{\left(\tan^{-1}{\frac{2}{1^2}}+\tan^{-1}{\frac{2}{2^2}}+...+\tan^{-1}{\frac{2}{n^2}}\right)}$ using, $\tan^{-1}{a}-\tan^{-1}{b}=\tan^{-1}{\frac{a-b}{1+ab}}$

Using the identity I rewrote $\tan^{-1}{\frac{2}{1^2}}+\tan^{-1}{\frac{2}{2^2}}+...+\tan^{-1}{\frac{2}{n^2}}$ as;

$\tan^{-1}{(2)}-\tan^{-1}{(0)}+\tan^{-1}{(3)}-\tan^{-1}{(1)}+\tan^{-1}{(4)}-\tan^{-1}{(2)}+...+\tan^{-1}{(n+1)}-\tan^{-1}{(n-1)}$

Which simplified to $-\tan^{-1}{(0)}-\tan^{-1}{(1)}+\tan^{-1}{(n+1)}$

Which simplified to $\tan^{-1}{\left(\frac{n}{n+2}\right)}$

Therefore the original limit is now $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+2}=1$

However, the answers say the limit approaches $-1$ and using my calculator I found that the tan-inverse chain approaches $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ which supports the answer given in the book. So where did I go wrong?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2153365/how-to-calculate-the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-arctan-frac2n2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait, what happened to $\tan^{-1} n$?  Your sum telescopes, but the lag is by $2$ terms, not $1$.  In particular,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \tan^{-1} \frac{2}{n^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n \tan^{-1} (n+1) - \tan^{-1} (n-1) = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \tan^{-1} n - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \tan^{-1} n \\= \tan^{-1} n + \tan^{-1} (n+1) - \tan^{-1} 0 - \tan^{-1} 1.$$

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot a $\tan^{-1}(n)$ , which gives you approximately an additional $\pi/2$ you need