# Finding the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \arctan\frac{2}{n^2}$ using Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I've been working with the series $$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \arctan\frac{2}{n^2}. $$

There is a nice solution to this using telescoping sums ([Showing that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arctan \left( \frac{2}{n^2} \right) =\frac{3\pi}{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243802/showing-that-sum-n-1-infty-arctan-left-frac2n2-right-frac3)), which comes out to $3\pi/4$. But I was also wondering if there was a solution using the Taylor series expansion of $\arctan$. Here is my work so far:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan\frac{2}{n^2} &= \arctan 2 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \arctan \frac{2}{n^2} \\
&= \arctan 2 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m\frac{\left(\frac{2}{n^2}\right)^{2m+1}}{2m+1} \\
&= \arctan 2 + \sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m\frac{2^{2m+1}}{2m+1}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n^2)^{2m+1}} \\
&= \arctan 2 + \sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m\frac{2^{2m+1}}{2m+1}(\zeta(4m+2)-1).
\end{align*}

Let $$f(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m(\zeta(4m+2)-1)x^{2m}.$$ Then integrating $f(x)$ and evaluating at $x = 2$ yields the original series. To find an expression for $f(x)$, I used the expansion $$\frac{\pi x \cot(\pi x)}{2} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \zeta(2n)x^{2n} = \zeta(2)x^2 + \zeta(4)x^4 + \zeta(6)x^6 + \cdots.$$

To filter out the terms with coefficient $\zeta(4n)$, consider $$\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{\pi x}{2}\cot(\pi x)+\frac{\pi ix}{2}\cot(\pi ix)\right) = \zeta(2)x^2+\zeta(6)x^6+\zeta(10)x^{10}+\cdots.$$

We then divide by $x^2$ and then plug in $\sqrt{ix}$ for $x$ to obtain $$-\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{ix}}(\cot(\pi\sqrt{ix})-\coth(\pi\sqrt{ix})) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m\zeta(4m+2)x^{2m}.$$ We also know that $\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^mx^{2m},$ so we have $$f(x) = -\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{ix}}(\cot(\pi\sqrt{ix})-\coth(\pi\sqrt{ix})) - \frac{1}{1+x^2}.$$

The integral of this (by WolframAlpha) is $$\frac{i}{2}(\ln\tan(\pi\sqrt{ix})-\ln\tanh(\pi\sqrt{ix})+\ln\cos(\pi\sqrt{ix})-\ln\cosh(\pi\sqrt{ix})) - \arctan x.$$ But evaluating this at $x=2$ and adding it to $\arctan 2$ yields $-\pi/4$, which is incorrect.

Interestingly enough, if I instead simplify $\ln\tan(y)+\ln\cos(y)$ to $\ln\sin(y)$ (where $y = \pi\sqrt{ix}$) and do the same for $\ln\tanh(y)+\ln\cosh(y)=\ln\sinh(y)$, it becomes $3\pi/4$ (the correct answer). So:

Are there issues with the radius of convergence or the domain of $\ln$ that I'm missing? And if so, how can the two different answers be reconciled? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can use the formula for the even integer zeta values, that is explicitly
$$\zeta(4m+2)=\zeta(2(2m+1))=\frac{B_{4m+2}(2\pi)^{4m+2}}{2(4m+2)!}$$

Comment: It seems that there is a discontinuity issue here. If you keep the long form with $\tan, \tanh$ etc., and let $x\to 2-$, you will get $3\pi/4$. Wherease if $x\to 2+$, you will get $-5\pi/4$. The average value is $-\pi/4$.